# Failover Load balance

Tags: failover, mysql-cluster, failovercluster

What is the best solution to have a backup for your servers? I have a Web server and a SQL data server. I would like to have fail over backup for each of them, I don't know what would I need. I've bought another 4 servers to have a backup for web and data and two server for domain controller and its backup. confused I am going on track or I lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft DPM can be used for backing up SQL and DC servers, with DAS/NAS or azure cloud as preferred storage.
It has a clean and simple GUI for configuring the backups.
Another 3rd party tools like Cloudberry and Backblaze can also be used if you have a small infrastructure and prefer a cost effective cloud backup software.
So if you back up your data to be 100% sure that it's safe and not just to make some backups, you'd better go with professional backup solution.